# How do we place image on top of another image

Tags: css, image, html

I want to place a picture on top of another, but i am baffled. Here is what i have done so far.

What i want to do is to place a logo.png inside main.png. But main.png is in a background image and i want to keep it that way. So how can i achieve this

HTML

```
<div class="ImageMain">
</div>

<div class="LogoMain">
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .ImageMain {
        z-index:1;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-image:url(../Resources/Images/HomeMain.jpg);
        background-size:cover;
        background-position:50% 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .LogoMain {
        z-index:2;
        background-image:url(../Resources/Images/Main%20Logo.png);
        position:relative;

    }
```

I also tried this.

```
CSS
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
.ImageMain {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(../Resources/Images/HomeMain.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.LogoMain {
    z-index:2;
    background-image:url(../Resources/Images/Main%20Logo.png);
    position:absolute;
```

I added the wrapper and made the logo position to absolute. I also added z index. It still isnt working.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is wrap the two images in a div, put its position to relative, leave the first image on display block, and put the second image on position absolute with top and left to 0.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="Main.jpg" alt="Home"/>
  <img src="Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" class="logo"/>
</div>
```

And for the css :

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/bYwh8/

A second solution would be to use the CSS3 multiple backgrounds, you can see an example in this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/azLPn/ and get more details here http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Comment: That kind of works, but i need the previous code intact, so no img tags. I want to use background images in both div tags.

Comment: You definitely need a wrapper with a relative position so it's children know where to be placed when positionned absolute. Except from this wrapper that you need to add, it's pretty easy to adapt the code I gave you.

Comment: Re-read the question. Post some answers, but i wouldnt be able to reply for a while. I have to sleep ( 1pm here ) So, i would get back to you when i wake up :). ( 7-8 hours )

Comment: What you can do is create a jsfiddle with your problem, or continue searching a bit by yourself, try to understand what you are doing in your css and you'll find the solution. What you get from stackoverflow is tips to help you, not people coding for you.
First what you can do is to set your divs width and height to the width and height of their background image, then the first div has no point to be absolute and the second should just be absolute with its top and left position to 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest way to do this:**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="image1.jpg" id="image1"/>
  <img src="image2.jpg" id="image2"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#image1{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

#image2{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
```

at this stage image2 is already on image1. If you want image2 to be on image1 and image1 to be partially visible, add this:

```
#image2{
  z-index:2;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

"Opacity" makes element transparent. Here opacity:0.75 means image2 would be 75% solid and 25% transparent.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is to include an image tag inside a div, and to add a background image to that div.

Update: I saw you solved the problem as I said, very nice! Now, to center correctly an absolute positioned div you can add negative values to each property (top, bottom, right and left) and it should work.

Comment: What i want to do is to place a logo.png inside the main.png. The main.png is a background image so i cant do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hurrah. I figured out how to do it with the background image.
here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RFnu2/1/.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="MainPic"/> </div>
  <div class="Logo" >
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1jSi1Kj" id="MainLogo"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#MainPic{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image:url(http://bit.ly/1nv5VHM)
}

#MainLogo{
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  z-index:2;
  width:20%;
}

.logo {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

but I couldnt figure out how to centre the logo so it would look funny, but it still works.